# showcasing one attribute of multiple instances from a model django/python

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models with multiple attributes and I would like to showcase a specific attribute which has multiple instances in another model:

```
class Carnet(models.Model):
....multiple attributes


class Consultation(models.Model):
    ....
    date_cons = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

There are multiple instances of `date_cons`. I would like to showcase the latest one added in an html code

The view method I used was this ( probably here is the problem )

```
def consultation(request, carnet_id):

    consultation = Consultation.objects.all()

    context = {
        'consultation' : consultation
    }

    return render(request, 'carnets/carnet.html',context)
```

tried showcasing that attribute in an html code using this syntax

```
{{consultation.date_cons}}
```

but it doesn't showcase anything.

How do I showcase this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a list of consultation instances. Therefore you must display them in your html accordingly.

Try to use this in your html:

```
{% for instance in consultation %}
   {{ instance.date_cons }}
{% endfor %}
```

For better readability, I'd use `consultations` (plural) for the name of the list, and use `consultation` for the instance in the `for` loop.

Comment: i would like to only display the latest consultation attributes, meaning (date_cons, poids_cons, taille_cons), 3 attributes of the latest instance of consultation, instance isn't an attribute in consultation, would it still work ? i also tried the order.by('-date_cons') but it didn't work, i even tried using :[1] to only get one consultation

Comment: This is another matter. Please accept this answer if it solves your problem in this question, then ask another question about ordering. Thank you.